# How to add two Fonts to java swing components, and make them automatically switch when user switches keyboard input language?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, localization

I'm working on an app where User should be able to input some text which contains both English and Persian(Same as Arabic: almost same characters and written from right to left ).

Currently i'm using fonts like Courier New which supports both languages but it looks really Ugly. I Want to use some better looking fonts, but these fonts only support one of these languages and show nonsense characters for the other language. So i need to use them based on text language.

So generally how can I make Java components (especially `swing.JTextField`, `swing.JListBox` and `swing.JTextComponent`) accept two fonts and switch appropriately to have a good looking GUI?

**Edit:** Here is an example of what i need. Let say user should input something like **(FPGA استفاده از )** and all of it in a single `swing.JTextField`. It means **(Using FPGA)** and FPGA is an abbreviation, so there is no Persian translation. I need to set a font with a better look and all fonts which support Unicode are ugly for the Persian part.

Now if I set font to something like `Times New Roman` ,which only supports Latin, then Persian characters would show as empty squares. also if i set font to something like `B Nazanin` ,which only supports Persian, then Latin characters would show as empty squares. How can I have both fonts in a single Java component **in the same time**.

Comment: *"especially `swing.JTextField`, `swing.JListBox` and `swing.JText`"*  There is no `JText` class in the API.  DYM  `JTextComponent` or  `JTextPane` or..?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking here, but see methods like [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-) ..

Comment: thanks for edit and you are correct @AndrewThompson . I just was trying to type JTextComponent. And about Font.canDisplayUpTo, it only tells me what i already know, some characters won't be displayed correctly.

Comment: *"I just was trying to type JTextComponent."*  You can [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32602623/edit) any time..  While you're there, you might also clarify what it is you're not sure about.

Comment: @AndrewThompson . I edited my question and added an example of what i mean. thanks for comment.

Comment: So.. your question boils down to 'how to support both English and Persian script in the same text component?'?  Why not have two text components?  It seems quite tricky to support both right-to-left and left-to-right orientation languages (Persian is R-t-L isn't it?) in the **same** field unless using a rich text component that would allow different fonts for different lines of the document.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Correct, Persian is R-t-L. Currently i'm using  two text components, one for Latin and the other for Persian. (for `JListBox` and `JTextField` I use a font supporting Unicode). I am sure you agree this is not the right way to do this,specially when it comes to more than two components. Also consider the Worst and very probable case when user is writing something in Latin, then changes keyboard to Persian and so on. Surely it's not simple to add new `JTextField` for each part, especially if user try to navigate to what written before and edit or probably delete them!!!!

Comment: I get exact same problem, other posts here implies that I need implement myself AbstractDocument, but I'm not sure how to finish it, I just set DefaultStyleDocument to a JTextField and detect segments of a text string, and call 'setCharacterAttributes' multiple times with different font hints as Attribute, but UI's painting step cannot switch font during it is painting multiple Element, implementing a new TextUI class is a hard task for me.

Comment: @DanielYeung . Finally I made the decision to create a font of my own and putting it in the app. You can merge two font together to create another font.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();
if(context.getLocale().toString().equals("en_GB")){
    .setFont(*font for english keyboard*);
}
else if(context.getLocale().toString().equals("fa_IR")){
    .setFont(*font for persian keyboard*);
}
```